# Почему Singleton считается неленивым?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Возьмём обычный Singleton.

```
 public class Single1 {

    private static final Single1 INSTANCE = new Single1();


    private Single1() {
        System.out.println("Single1 - Constructor");
    }

    public static Single1 getInstance(){
        System.out.println("Single1.getInstance");
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

В конструкторе сделаем вывод в System.out.
При работе программы видно, что конструктор вызывается при первом вызове getInstance! 
Тем не менее, считается, что данный синглтон неленивый и инициализируется сразу при загрузке класса.
Вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дело не в первом вызове `getInstance()`, а в первом обращении к классу `Single1`.

Если Вы создадите еще один статический метод, не `getInstance()`, который просто выводит на экран строку, то тоже увидите инициализацию `INSTANCE`.

Ленивым синглетоном считается именно тот, который инициализируется при прямой необходимости в инстансе (то есть при вызове именно `getInstance()`, а не другого метода класса). Эта реализация не удовлетворяет сказанному, следовательно это не ленивый синглетон).

Comment: спасибо! также в § 12.4.1 java language specification описано, в каких случаях происходит инициализация

Answer (score 1):

В java сами классы тоже являются объектами, как и экземпляры этого класса. Только создаются они по мере того как класс используется в коде - в единственном экземпляре на каждый загрузчик. Все что static относится к самому классу, а не к экземпляру. Следовательно, все инициализации static произойдут в момент создания объекта- класса, а не в момент первого обращения к объекту-экземпляру.